How can the plus sign created by VS's "Split string literals on enter" feature be put at the beginning of the new line?
If I have a long string and I press Enter to break it down, it will be turned like so:
var x = "LOOOOOOONG" + 
    " STRING";

Is there a way to enforce Visual Studio so that it automatically becomes like this instead?
var x = "LOOOOOOONG" 
    + " STRING";

